# Use cases between interface implementations

Tags: java, interface, callback, anonymous-class

I know two ways to use an Interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

1. Approach: Using `implements`:

   ```
   public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

       @Override
       myMethod(){}

   }
   ```

   I'm using an Interface this way most of the time, if the interface is a contract like:

   ```
   MyInterface foo = new MyClass();
   ```

   Now I can control MyClass with the provided methods of the Interface.
   This is also nice for collections. If there are some classes which implements `MyInterface` I have a common thread:

   ```
   List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
   ```
2. Approach: Using it as an `anonymous class`:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
       public MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface(){   
            @Override
            public void myMethod(){}            
       };
   }
   ```

   This approach I'm using for callbacks with dependcy injection like this:

   ```
   public class MyOtherClass {
       public MyInterface myInterface;

       // Using setter injection here
       public void setInterface(MyInterface interface){
           myInterface = interface;
       }
   }
   ```

   MyOtherClass is calling `myInterface.myMethod()` where it is appropriate.

A callback can be realized with the first approach by using the `this pointer` too. Now I would like to know which approach should be used for a callback and why? I have seen both and I don't know where the real benefit is.

As I see it, that's the only difference where I can choose between the first and second approach. If I'm wrong here please tell me another difference. I'm asking this to be able to select the proper tool for different situations.

In addition I would like to know another situation but a callback, where I can use the second approach.

Comment: They are 2 different things. The first approach uses inheritance while the second approach is using composition. The choice of either depends on which is more meaningful in the context of your interface and classes.

Comment: @shyam This is exactly the point where I'm lost, to find the right context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of using a named or an anonymous interface implementation depends on several things:

- **Are you planning to reuse some of the logic in the implementation?** - If the answer is "yes", use the first approach; otherwise, use the second approach.
- **Do you need to implement complex logic with lots of external interactions?** - If the answer is "yes", use the first approach; otherwise, use the second approach.
- **Does your interface have multiple methods, some of which may meaningfully do nothing?** - If the answer is "yes", use the first approach, or make a "default" class with all implementations doing nothing; otherwise, use the second approach.

In the end, the biggest difference between these two approaches is mostly non-technical: it has to do with readability of your resultant code. After all, anonymous classes are a little more than "syntactic sugar" - you can perfectly implement your system with only named classes. If you think that a named implementation reads better, use the first approach; if you think that an anonymous one works better, use the second approach.

Comment: All in all the named implementation should be prefered in favor of reusability?

Comment: @SteveBenett Sometimes, there is simply no reusability to be had - for example, when your class is a simple conduit providing the "glue logic" to connect a callback with a method or two, performing the "heavy lifting". However, if you think that the callback code you're writing could be reused, you should definitely go for a named class. One way to know for sure is if you see yourself copy-pasting code from one anonymous class into another anonymous class.